# What are the differences between .dmg and .app file?

Tags: macos, installation, dmg

What are the specific differences between disk image file and .app extension in macOS

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this, since pretty much everything is different between them. It's a little like asking the specific difference between a tuna fish and a cardboard box. Can you clarify what you're actually trying to understand?

Comment: @GordonDavisson The major similarity is: with both facilitate installing an app on your mac. I suppose you only download .dmg files. But never download .app files. They get created off of the .dmg? Is that right? And ultimately how what does a .dmg contain? how is it different from the contents of a .app? What transition needs to happen from a .dmg for it to produce a .app? 

Is that more clear?

Comment: Interesting to note is that other operating systems interpret `.app` files as actually being just a folder, containing the equivalent of what you'd find in the "Program Files" folder in Windows for that program. Within that `.app` folder there's an executable, which is what runs when you click an icon for your `.app`. So, in macOS, `.app`s seem to be folders with some kind of special execution; normally the execute permission for a folder just opens it, in this case it runs an executable present inside them. Don't know enough about `.dmg` to make this an answer right now but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

A disk image file or `.dmg` is a copy of a disk, a *virtual disk*. In it's simplest form a disk image is a file containing what would normally reside on a physical device say, a hard drive, thumb drive, floppy disk, etc.

A macOS application or `.app` file is a *bundle* or a collection of related resources from the view of the OS. For example the `Safari.app` bundle contains not just the executable, but Information property lists, resources such as icons, plug-ins, etc. Unlike in Windows, on macOS an *application* is not just an executable. It can and should be viewed as a self-contained entity that has the necessary frameworks and libraries to function on it's own. This is why you can simply drag and drop a `.app` to "install" a program on macOS. *Finder* in macOS treats this bundle as a single entity which is why you can just double click and launch it as if it were just an executable. If you right click and select *Show Package Contents* on a `.app` bundle you will see that it more resembles a directory. As an aside, a bundle may contain another bundle inside it, so an `.app` may have another `.app` inside such as a helper, sub-tool, etc.

In macOS how is a `.dmg` related to a `.app`? They're *not* really, but the delivery of an application is often done via a `.dmg` disk. If you download a `.dmg` from an application provider macOS will mount it as a virtual disk, show you its contents which often contains a bundle with a `.app` extension that you then copy and paste locally to install the application.